# Trip Routes that Visit 9 of 10 Cities

Tags: graph-theory

There are 10 cities on this island. For each pair of cities, they may have a bidirectional path.

A **trip route** is defined as a route which start on a city e.g. $A$, goes to 8 of 9 other cities exactly once (by the paths), and goes back to city $A$. (i.e. a trip route is a cycle of 9 cities/paths.)

What is the minimum number of the paths on this island; so that for each city, there exist a trip route that doesn't visit it?

---

*This puzzle is taken from Indonesia National Science Olympiad in Mathematics 2011.*

Comment: "goes to 8 of 9 other cities exactly" means from A you should have a connection between one of the cities? or it is at least 8?

Comment: If the cities are labeled 1 to 10, then a cycle of `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1` is an example of a trip route that doesn't visit 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 15

After playing around with it I realized that each city must have at least 3 paths so that if one city goes down there are still 2 paths to enter and leave the city.

Then I tried to construct the cities such that each city ONLY has 3 paths, the minimum required.

Although I am unable to provide a mathematical proof.

> [image: Map of cities]

Comment: You have a mathematical proof in your answer: there can't be a city with less than 3 roads to it! so you have a minimum number, as you have shown this minimum is doable, you have your demonstration.

Comment: This is called graph theory. It's a really interesting part of math.

Comment: "goes to 8 of 9 other cities exactly",

Comment: Also, because your graph is vertex-transitive, just showing one 9-city tour shows that any city can be the one left out of the tour.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I had to search up what that word meant, but yes I wanted to make it symmetric so it's easy to test.

Comment: Yep, this is correct! To prove that each city must have at least 3 paths: Suppose city $A$ only connects to 2 cities $B$ and $C$. There will never be a trip route that doesn't visit $B$ (or $C$), because we need a path to come in and leave out city $A$.

Comment: @athin Unless there's only 3 cities, in which case you only need 2 paths :^)